# Programatically view the number of PowerBI licences

Tags: sql-server, rest, powerbi, azure-powershell

I've tried searching for either a [REST Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/) or powershell cmdlet that will tell me the number of powerbi licences we have.

I know I can view this in the Azure Portal or in the [Microsoft 365 Admin centre](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-admin-manage-licenses) but I want to be able to programatically get the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rui Romano's [PBI Monitor](https://github.com/RuiRomano/pbimonitor) gathers this data and a whole lot more.  So you can implement that, or refer to how it gets this data from the Microsoft Graph in [Fetch Graph.ps1](https://github.com/RuiRomano/pbimonitor/blob/main/Fetch%20-%20Graph.ps1).